# iOS Launch screen code not running

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I heard about the new feature which xcode 6 brings, that allows you to make a storyboard as a launchscreen.
Now..

Is there a way to control UI elements on the launchscreen story board via a viewcontroller?
(to show a loading screen or something)

I tried it, I simply did a  `println("Here's the view loaded on the loadingscreen")` in the viewdidload on the controller which is referred to the view in the launchscreen story board, but there's no output at all..

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong.

No code is associated with the launch screen. You can't run any logic. It is purely there so that you can use AutoLayout to layout the launch screens for different sizes of device.

Comment: Thanks didn't knew that ^^

Comment: @RaVeN no worries. It's a bit misleading because you can associate subclasses and stuff. But none of the code will ever actually be run.

Answer (score 4):

You can't specify any class to launch screen and run code there. The storyboard file is only an alternative for multiple splash screens (Launch images). You can use a single storyboard/xib file based launch screen for different iOS platforms and orientations (You can handle that using Auto Layout).

The major point that you need to remember is, at that point the application is not completely launched.
So `viewDidLoad` or any view life cycle methods will not be invoked.